# Searching Jira for label !=

Tags: jira, label

I have a label set for some of my issues. When searching labels="ab" I get the relevant ones, but I cannot seem to find the right syntax for asking labels!="ab". 
How can I query for the ones not equal to ab?

Answer (score 73):

!= works for me although it only shows issues that have labels
If I want to show all issues that do not have a certain label I have to do

```
(labels is EMPTY OR labels != 'mylabel')
```

This behaviour is currently intended by the Jira-Team. A suggestion to change it has been posted in the [Developer-Jira](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-23030) and can be voted for.

Comment: Cool, could you accept the answer so other people can benefit from this too

Comment: Why is this not accepted? This is the correct answer. cc: @Lihilu

Comment: guess @lihilu did a "I got my answer and ran" :)

Answer (score 10):

```
labels != 'ab'
```

Will display all issues with labels that differ from 'ab', **but not empty labels**.

to show those with empty labels too:

```
labels != 'ab' OR labels is empty
```

Comment: I get results for labels = ab, but when adding ! before the = I get 0 results.
BTW - it does not give me an error, like the !~ gives, it just says 0 results. If I try labels = empty it gives me results, so for sure I have items with labels != ab

Comment: Not exactly, searching for 'labels != ab' will not output issues with labels that are empty. It will only list issues that have non empty labels and their labels does not include 'ab'. Please try what I've told you to do - click on an issue label and then change the '=' to '!=' and tell me what happens.